# Why does strcmp always give 0

Tags: file, unix, doubly-linked-list, getopt, ocelot

I build a doubly linked list which orders strings in alphabetical order as you add them. The strings come from an input file and I use getopt to get the input file from the command line. When i test the doubly linked list by itself it works fine and sorts the words accordingly, but once I use the strings from the file, the strcmp always returns 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>


typedef struct Node{
    char *word;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;
Node *tail = NULL;

Node* createNode(char *word){
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->word = word;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

int compare(char *word, char *current){
    return strcmp(word, current);
}

void insertNode(Node *newNode){
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        return;
    }

    Node *current = head;
    int comp;
    do{
        comp = compare(newNode->word, current->word);
        printf("word: %s, current: %s, comp = %d\n",newNode->word, current->word, comp);

        //Only inserting node when word is less than current
        if(comp < 0){
            if(current->prev == NULL){
                head = newNode;
                current->prev = head;
                head->next = current;
                return;
            }
            newNode->next = current;
            newNode->prev = current->prev;
            current->prev->next = newNode;
            current->prev = newNode;

            printf("comp: %d, New node added for: %s\n\n", comp, newNode->word);

            return;
        }

        if(comp > 0 && current->next == NULL){
            current->next = newNode;
            newNode->prev = current;
            tail = newNode;
            printf("New node: %s, added at the tail\n\n", newNode->word);
            return;
        }

        //printf("past first if\n");
        if(comp > 0 && current->next){
            printf("enter com > 0\n");
            printf("current: %s\n", current->word);
            current = current->next;
            printf("current updated: %s\n\n", current->word);
        }

        //If both words are equal just drop newNode
        if(comp == 0){
            //free(newNode);
            return;
        }

    } while(current != NULL);

}

void printList(int reverse){
    if (reverse == 0){
        Node *current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", current->word);
            current = current->next;
        }
    } else if(reverse == 1){
        Node *current = tail;
        while (current != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", current->word);
            current = current->prev;
        }
    }
}

void printListFile(FILE* fp, int reverse) {
    if (reverse == 0){
        Node *current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", current->word);
            current = current->next;
        }
    } else if(reverse == 1){
        Node *current = tail;
        while (current != NULL) {
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", current->word);
            current = current->prev;
        }
    }

}

void freeList() {
    while (head != NULL) {
        Node* next = head->next;
        free(head->word);
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    extern char *optarg;
    extern int optind;
    int dflag = 0, oflag = 0;
    char* inputFile = NULL;
    char* outputFile = NULL;
    int c, err = 0;

    //Usage
    static char usage[] = "usage: %s doublesort [-d] [-o output_file_name] input_file_name\n";

    //Getopt
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "do")) != -1)
        switch (c) {
            case 'd':
                dflag = 1;
                break;
            case 'o':
                oflag = 1;
                outputFile = optarg;
                break;
            case '?':
                err = 1;
                break;

        }



    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (optind >= argc) {
        printf("optind = %d, argc = %d\n", optind, argc);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing input file name\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (optind < argc) {
        inputFile = argv[optind];
    }

    FILE* fin = stdin;
    FILE* fout = stdout;
    if (inputFile != NULL) {
        fin = fopen(inputFile, "r");
        if (fin == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open file %s for reading.\n", inputFile);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(oflag == 1){
        if (outputFile != NULL) {
            fout = fopen(outputFile, "w");
            if (fout == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open file %s for writing.\n", outputFile);
                if (fin != stdin) {
                    fclose(fin);
                }
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //Inserting node into doubly link list
    char buf[100];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fin) != NULL) {
        int len = strlen(buf);
        if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
            buf[len - 1] = '\0';
        }
        insertNode(createNode(buf));
    }

    if(oflag == 1){
        printListFile(fout, dflag);
    }
    else{
        printList(dflag);
    }

    // free memory and close files
    freeList();
    if (fin != stdin) {
        fclose(fin);
    }
    if (fout != stdout) {
        fclose(fout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I feel like its an issue with the head storing but not sure how. Im new to C and we are using putty/UNIX which makes it more difficult.

Comment: All the nodes are using the same `buf`.

Comment: Any recommendation on how to fix? Still not entirely sure why it doesnt work.

Comment: In `createNode`, you initialize the new node with `newNode->word = word;` The `word` parameter is always the same `buf` variable from `main`, so all nodes use `buf` as their `word`. And naturally, if you compare the `buf` against itself, it always compares equal. You presumably want to make a copy of the string and save the copy. (Your `freeList` function already makes this assumption since it calls `free(head->word)`, which requires that you used `malloc` to allocate the word buffer.)

Comment: I understand now what your saying, however, I though i was comparing the newNode (with the word from the buf) to current (with the value from the head), and from there keep looping through the link list until it finds it appropiate place on it; but when I run it it compares the buf with 'buf'

Comment: Use a debugger to see what is happening. `current->word` is also `buf`.